# Using bitwise operators multiply an integer by 3, but return max if overflow

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

This is for a homework problem I am currently stuck on. I have to multiply an integer by 3, if there if overflow return the maximum (0x7FFFFFFF) and underflow return the minimum (0x80000000). I am using 32bit numbers and am restricted to only using the operators: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>

I feel as though I have solved it, but when I run the professors tests the case x = 0x7FFFFFFF incorrectly returns 0x7FFFFFFd. There could be other tests failing, but that is the first one that fails and it doesn't run the other tests.

This is my code so far:

```
int satMul3(int x) {
    int threex = x + x + x; //Definition of multiplication 3x = x+x+x
    int signx = x >> 31; //Makes bit all same number as MSB (1s = neg 0s = pos)
    int sign3 = threex >> 31; //Same as signx but for the result of x*3
    int overflow = signx ^ sign3; //Checks if signs are same. 0s if same sign
    int tmin = 0x80000000;
    int tmax = 0x7FFFFFFF;
    int answer = (sign3 & tmin) | (~sign3 & tmax);
    //Gets answer for overflow, if sign3 is negative returns Tmin else tmax

    return (overflow & answer) | (~overflow & threex); //If overflow is 1,
    //signs are the same so return x*3, if overflow is 0, then signs are
    //different so return the saturated answer
}
```

Hopefully it is just a simple error, but if not any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you taking in to account of the "sign" of zero correctly? I suspect not. remember the number is in two's compliment. You likely need a line to check either if int x == 0 or if threex == 0. I'll leave it to you how to do that with ! ~ & ^ | + << >> and handle adjusting your return appropriately.

Comment: In addition to the error with the polarity of `overflow`, your approach is fundamentally broken. Consider a number like `1431655766`, which is positive and representable in 32-bit 2's complement. `3*1431655766 == 4294967298`, which is *not* representable in 32-bit 2's complement **and** does not have the MSB set.

Comment: I am not sure where I am going wrong with the "sign" of 0. Shouldn't it just have the MSB of 0? I realized there was an error with where I put the answer and threex which I fixed. But my approach was if the sign of the result differed from the original sign of x then there was an overflow. Am I missing another case?

Comment: @Henry First of, if you want anybody to see what you comment, include `@username` in your comment. Second, you are missing the case where there was overflow and the MSB of the overflowed result is the same as the MSB of the original value.

Comment: @EOF sorry this is my first time posting and I'm not sure exactly how to check for that. So unless there is some way to check for that and I am just missing it, it would seem my approach is broken. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Henry Well, your approach is broken *for multipliers greater than two*. Since you have replaced `3*x` with`x+x+x`, and your approach would work for `2*x == x + x`, you might see how to do `3*x`. A warning though: signed overflow is *undefined behavior* in C. I recommend casting to `unsigned` first.

Comment: @EOF okay so if I do twox = x + x then check for overflow, then repeat for threex = twox + x and check for overflow again?

Comment: @Henry Yes, I believe that would correctly identify all possible overflows.